# issue where len(list) is coming back as out of index

Tags: python, list

I'm making a random password generator and in my script I have the following bit of code.

```
for x in range (0, pl):
                y=random.randint(0,len(List))
                passLet=(List[y])
                password +=passLet
```

Whenever I run the script, an error pops up stating that y is out of List's index. To add to the confusion, I have the same for statement earlier in the script that uses a random integer to retrieve a value from the exact same list but that has never had this issue. I could really use some help.

Comment: `randint` includes both endpoints. If you're using it as an index, you probably want `randrange`, which excludes the end value, just like `range` does.

Comment: @Blckknght: Or for this particular use case, just use `passLet = random.choice(List)` since that's the goal anyway (on Python 3.6+, [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) plus `''.join` could replace the whole loop).